# Flask app getting 0x8007000d error with IIS

Tags: flask, iis

I'm trying to get a very basic flask app to work on IIS 10 running on Windows Server 2019.
I followed the HTTPPlatform Handler instructions from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

But I keep getting HTTP 500.19 errors with error code 0x8007000d. From googling, I suspect the problem is in my web.config, but I don't know what is wrong. The app works fine from the command line.
This is my web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="D:\python39\python.exe"
                  arguments="D:\inetpub\wwwroot\flasktest.py"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="d:\logs\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="9010" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
#app.debug = True

@app.route("/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def home():
  return render_template('main.html', hello = 'hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=9010)
```

this is my main.html

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="leftrow1">
      {{ hello }}
    </div>
    <div class="leftrow2">
    </div>
    <div class="leftrow3">
    </div>
    <div class="leftrow4">
    </div>

    <div class="main_frame_1">
    </div>
    <div class="main_frame_2">
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and this is the layout.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %} 
  {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Update: based on comments received, adding additional error info
This is the error I get (without installing httpplatformhandler), nothing is in eventlog when this occurs:
[image: 500.19 error message]
This is the error I get after installing httpplatformhandler:
[image: 500.3 error message]
with the 500.3 message, I also get a bunch of event 1000 from HttpPlatformHandler in event log:
[image]

Comment: Download and install HttpPlatformHandler please https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler

Comment: Can you show me the details of your error page? or you can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view specific detailed error message.

Comment: one of the suggestions I found when googling 0x80070057 (https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/866 ) was to uninstall httpplatformhandler because .net core have it baked in (I have .net core 3.1.6). So, I'm not sure which way to continue, with or without installing httpplatformhandler.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I'm encountering the same issue trying to make a simple flask app work with httpPlatformHandler

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the correct permission to access D:\python39\python.exe and D:\inetpub\wwwroot\flasktest.py.

1. Open IIS Manager -> Select the site you added the HttpPlatformHandler
2. Click Handler Mappings in the feature view -> select the HttpPlatformHandler
3. Click Edit Feature Permission in the Action Panel
4. Make sure you have check the Execute permission

Comment: I tried this, but still getting 500.3 error

Comment: In your event log, I found that the image you posted are general information, can you show me the Details information?

Comment: only thing there seems to be "<EventData> <Data>Process '0' failed to start. Port = 22700, Error Code = '-2147024809'.</Data> </EventData> </Event>"

Comment: Make sure IIS_IUSRS has python39 and wwwroot access permissions. If this does not resolve the problem, try using failed request tracing.